Method not supported execption just with one controller Spring
Good morning every one, I'm having a hard time with this issue. I could work around but I want to understand why this is happening. So far I'm working with Spring, Spring Security, Data Rest and Data Mongo DB.
Until now, there has been no issue with DAO and controllers, everything seems to work fine. I've added a new Document:
@Document
public class PlanDeEntrenamiento {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String nombre;
  private String objetivo;
  private String descripcion;
  private List<SesionDePlan> sesiones;
  private String autor;
}

This one is the DAO:
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "planes", itemResourceRel = "plan",
    collectionResourceRel = "planes")
public interface PlanDeEntrenamientoDAO extends MongoRepository<PlanDeEntrenamiento, String> {
  List<PlanDeEntrenamiento> findByNombre(String nombre);
  List<PlanDeEntrenamiento> findByObjetivo(String objetivo);
}

And this the Security Configuration:
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authRequest -> authRequest
            .requestMatchers("/api/autenticacion/cambioPassword").authenticated()
            .requestMatchers("/api/autenticacion/login",
                "/api/autenticacion/registro/**",
                "/api/autenticacion/reset-password").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/invitaciones").authenticated()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/invitaciones/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/fichas/aprobado").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/fichas/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/ejercicios").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/planes").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/planes/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/ejercicios/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/equipamientos").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/usuarios/existe-email").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/usuarios/search/existsByNombre").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .sessionManagement(sessionManager ->
            sessionManager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authenticationProvider(this.PROVIDER)
        .addFilterBefore(this.FILTER, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
  }

Now, I create a controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/planes")
public class PlanDeEntrenamientoController {
  @Autowired
  PlanDeEntrenamientoDAO planDeEntrenamientoDAO;
  @Autowired
  SesionDAO sesionDAO;

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<PlanDeEntrenamientoResponse>> getPlanes() {
    List<PlanDeEntrenamiento> planes = planDeEntrenamientoDAO.findAll();
    List<PlanDeEntrenamientoResponse> planesResponse = new ArrayList<>();
    planesResponse = planes.stream().map(plan -> {
      PlanDeEntrenamientoResponse planResponse = new PlanDeEntrenamientoResponse();
      planResponse.setId(plan.getId());
      planResponse.setNombre(plan.getNombre());
      planResponse.setObjetivo(plan.getObjetivo());
      planResponse.setDescripcion(plan.getDescripcion());
      planResponse.setAutor(plan.getAutor() != null ? plan.getAutor() : null);
      return  planResponse;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(planesResponse);
  }
  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<PlanDeEntrenamiento> getPlanes(@PathVariable String id) {
    PlanDeEntrenamiento planDeEntrenamiento = planDeEntrenamientoDAO.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(planDeEntrenamiento);
  }
  @PostMapping("/{id}/agregarSesiones")
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> getPlanes(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody
  AgregarSesionesRequest request) {
    PlanDeEntrenamiento plan = planDeEntrenamientoDAO.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    plan.getSesiones().forEach(sesion -> {
      Sesion nuevaSesion = new Sesion();
      nuevaSesion.setNombre(sesion.getNombre());
      nuevaSesion.setFichas(sesion.getFichas());
      nuevaSesion.setGrupo(request.getGrupo());
      LocalDate fechaSesion = request.getFecha().plusDays(sesion.getDia() - 1);
      nuevaSesion.setFecha(fechaSesion);
      nuevaSesion.setUnidad(request.getUnidad());
      sesionDAO.save(nuevaSesion);
    });
    return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
  }
}

And after that, when I want to post, put or patch something with the endpoints provided by data rest, the log is this one:
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' is not supported] 
Of course I can manually define the endopoints but the point using data rest is not having to do that and I've done nothing different from others Controllers, where I have no problems at all. Any tip would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Ok, the problem was this method:
  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<PlanDeEntrenamiento> getPlanes(@PathVariable String id) {
    PlanDeEntrenamiento planDeEntrenamiento = planDeEntrenamientoDAO.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(planDeEntrenamiento);
  }

I have deleted it because I see there is no need for it, I had it because some test I did before and then didn't delete it. After deleting it, every put or patch to "/{id}" started working again. However, if someone can explain this to me that would be helpful.

Also, the @GetMapping() caused the methods over the endpoint the same problem, so I understand that overriding some endpoint from data rest force you to define the different methods to that endpoint via controller
